# regex.replace not replacing all in this expression.

Tags: .net, regex, powershell-2.0

```
[regex]::replace('test test','^(.*?)test', 'barf')
```

returns 'barf test'

Why doesn't it replace all occurrences of 'test'?   This must have something to do with the position at which a subsequent replace iteration begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: you anchored it at the beginning of the input (`^`) and your first group (`(.*?)`) did not capture anything (since the first occurrence of `test` was found right after the beginning of line and you use a lazy quantifier -- furthermore you don't use the capture in your replacement string. Had you used a "normal" quantifier, the last occurrence of `test` would have been replaced).

Long answer: **a regex never needs to match the whole input, only the parts which are necessary**. What's more, when cycling through an input, the regex engine will start the next round from the position where it successfully completed a match.

Here, you want to replace a sequence of characters which is `test`. Note that it will also means that `testosterone` will be matched (or `untested`). If you want to match `test` as a "word", use the word anchor `\b`.

This works (`test`ed on Powershell v2):

```
[regex]::replace('test test','\btest\b', 'barf')
```

The engine in action looks something like this:

```
# beginning
regex: |\btest\b
input: |test test
# \b: matched,  beginning of input followed by word character
regex: \b|test\b
input: |test test
# literal matching of t, then e, then s, then t
regex: \btest|\b
input: test| test
# \b: match, word character followed by non word character
regex: \btest\b|
input: test| test
# replacement
regex: \btest\b|
input: barf| test
# beginning of second round
regex: |\btest\b
input: barf| test
# \b: match, word character followed by non word character
regex: \b|test\b
input: barf| test
# t: not matched. Failed matching. Proceeding to next character
regex: |\btest\b
input: barf |test
# \b: match
regex: \b|test\b
input: barf |test
# literal matching of t, then e, then s, then t
regex: \btest|\b
input: barf test|
# \b: match, word character followed by end of input
regex: \btest\b|
input: barf test|
# replacement
regex: \btest\b|
input: barf barf|
# beginning of next round
regex: |\btest\b
input: barf barf|
# end of input: end of processing
```

Comment: The OP asked about the behaviour of a specific regex - there is no way anyone can say it is 'wrong'.

Comment: @Borodin when a regex is misleaded, it is misleaded. `(.*?)` serves _no purpose_.

Comment: @borodin is correct, my OP isn't "wrong". It is simply a contrived example to illustrate a behavior I wanted to understand.  I got a good  explanation, now I understand.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn if you want I can simulate the regex engine in the works with your original expression

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.*?` matches as less as possible including the empty string. So you are matching only the first "test" and replacing it.

The main reason is because your anchor `^`. That means your regex matching only once from the start, after the replacement the regex would continue after the replacement but at this point the anchor is not true, so your regex is done.

From your comment

> BUT! WHY DOESN'T this replace both: [regex]::replace("testntest",'^(.*?)test', 'barf')`(The "test`ntest" has a newline in the middle so the second instance should match the ^

The anchor `^` matches only the **start of the string** per default, if you use the modifier `m` (Multiline), then the anchor `^` will match the **start of the row**

If you want to replace all occurrences of "test" then match only "test", without `^.*?`

Comment: I know what ? means but I'm looking for a deeper explanation of why this fails.  After all ,replace is documented as "replace ALL occurrences that match the pattern.  This pattern specifies 0 or more of anything followed by 'test'. After the first replace I have 'barf test' so why doesn't that match for a second occurrence?  After all, if I run the same replace against the results of the first replace, 'barf test' becomes 'barf barf'.

Comment: That because your anchor `^`. That means your regex matching only once from the start, after the replacement the regex would continue after the replacement but at this point the anchor is not true, so your regex is done.

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect a second replacement to result in just 'barf' as the pattern matches the entire string. I don't have a VS to hand to test it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The problem is not with the `/(.*?/` as the effect is the same with or without it. Removing the anchor `/^/`, on the other hand, makes all the difference.

Comment: You are correct, the answer is incorrect, though the later explanation by @stema seemed to be the  full answer. stema, if you edit your answer to reflect your comment I'll keep it flagged. BUT!  WHY DOESN'T this replace both: `[regex]::replace("test`ntest",'^(.*?)test', 'barf')`  (The "test`ntest" has a newline in the middle so the second instance should match the ^

Comment: @ElroyFlynn no, by default, `^` matches the beginning of the _input_. And again, why? You want to replace `test`, just make your regex `\btest\b`!

Comment: @ElroyFlynn see my answer for the explanation of why `\btest\b` works

Comment: @fge, the example is just an example for illustrating behavior.  I don't really have a business case for replacing 'test' with 'barf' multiple times in 'test test'. But thanks for the explanation, if I add regexoptions.multiline I get both replaces.  stema, I'm still waiting on your edit of the anser

Comment: @Borodin I explained that with the anchor `^` in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because once the first 'test' is found at the beginning of the string (with `/(.*?)/` matching an empty string) the next search starts *after* that string. Straight away the `/^/` cannot match, so no more replacements are made.

The regex engine doesn't find all ways that a pattern could possibly match: it claims the first match that it comes across and moves on.

Comment: "The regex engine doesn't find all ways that a pattern could possibly match: it claims the first match that it comes across and moves on." <-- wrong with POSIX regex engines. A POSIX regex engine will always attempt to find the longest, leftmost match (`star|starlight` will match `starlight` if given `I love starlights` as an input`

Comment: My meaning was that no regex engine finds *all ways* the pattern could match. So `/^.*?/` can't match twice with two different lengths.

Answer (score -1):

The question mark is the lazy operator.  It tries to quit as soon as it can.  Remove it and thy will be done.

Comment: This is just wrong. Removing the question mark has the effect of replacing the entire string instead.

Comment: Isn't that what he wants?  What else could happen?

Comment: It was an experiment, and I think he expected *every occurrence* of 'test' to be replaced with 'barf'. `/^(.*)test/` simply replaces the entire string with 'barf'.